# Deletion Trigger not working?

Tags: apex, trigger

I want my trigger to prevent deletion of Account records, the code doesn't show any error but my `Account` records are still being deleted?
here is my code

```
trigger PreventAccountDelete on Account(before delete){
    for(Account a :[select Id from Account where Id IN:Trigger.old])
    {
        System.debug('Cant delete');
    }

}
```

Comment: You're not doing anything in your code.

Answer (score 2):

In order to prevent delete transaction to be committed to DB, you need to [addError](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm) to record, that should not be deleted

```
trigger PreventAccountDelete on Account (before delete) {

    for(Account acc : trigger.old){
        acc.addError('Account Cannot be deleted');
    }
}
```

to test this behavior run the following unit-test

```
@isTest
private class PreventAccountDeleteTest {

    @isTest
    static void testPreventAccDel(){
        Account accRecord = new Account(name='testAccount');
        insert accRecord;

        Test.startTest();

        try{
            delete accRecord;
            System.assertEquals(false, 'An Error was expected');
        }catch(DMLexception e){
            System.assertEquals(true, e.getMessage().contains('Account Cannot be deleted'),'Account Cannot be deleted');                       
        }

        Test.stopTest();

    }
}
```

Comment: No  @Alexander Berehovskiy I am getting errors while running the unit test case

Comment: what error do you have?

Comment: I actually corrected the problem of another Trigger firing on my intended object but now there is this strange behavior exhibited by my trigger.

Comment: When i use the addError method in place of my System.debug there is a validation error which prevents the record from being deleted, but when i use the System.debug method the record still gets deleted.

Comment: System.debug should not prevent record deletion. Writes the specified message, in string format, to the execution debug log. Only addError prevents record deletion, by means of transaction interruption via custom validation rule

Comment: @AlexanderBerehovskiy - You should put a `system.assertEquals(false,'An Error was expected);` line after the delete DML. otherwise if the record IS deleted the test will still pass :)

Comment: @Eric you're right. I've updated my answer

Comment: @AlexanderBerehovskiy - With your update the test will fail every time. You need it right after the DML statement

Comment: @Eric yes... Advice for me from me - Don't answer questions while tired :)